# Custom claims with Jwt Bearer Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have an application that uses `JwtBearerAuthentication`. I am trying to add my application claims to the `User(ClaimsPrincipal)` at the beginning of each request. I managed to do that using `ClaimsTransformationOptions`:

```
app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions
{
    Transformer = new ClaimsTransformer<TUser, TRole>()
});
```

and in my `TransformAsync`:

```
public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
{
    var services = context.Context.RequestServices;
    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<TRole>>();

    var userId = 1; // Get the UserId from my store, let say its 1 for now

    if (userId != 0)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        var claimsPrincipal = await new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>(userManager, roleManager, _optionsAccessor)
                .CreateAsync(user);

        context.Principal.AddIdentities(claimsPrincipal.Identities);
    }

    return context.Principal;
}
```

So far so good and the claims are being loaded from the database and added to the `context.Principal`. My problem is once I reach the controller, the identities are being overwritten !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved this problem by putting the `app.UseClaimsTransformation` after `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` which made sure that whenever `JWT` is going to amend the `ClaimsPrincipal` the `ClaimsTransformation` will be called afterwards to add my own claims.